# Positioning button element on image using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working with this UI design, where I created an avatar image and also an upload button. My challenge is positioning the upload button on the image as shown below

expectation

[image]

but this is what I came up with

[image]

```js
document.querySelector('#btnOpenFileDialog').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#fileLoader').click();
});
```

```css
.image-cropper {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.edit-img-btn {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: .5rem;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4169E2;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
}

.edit-img-btn i {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<span class="image-cropper" style=" width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="">
  </span>

<input type="file" id="fileLoader" style="display: none;" />

<button class="edit-img-btn" id="btnOpenFileDialog"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place all of it inside of an inline block element with `position: relative` you can adjust the position to fit your needs. Below is an example.

```js
document.querySelector('#btnOpenFileDialog').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#fileLoader').click();
});
```

```css
/*wrapper with position: relative */
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image-cropper {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.edit-img-btn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px; /* 5px up from the bottom */
  right: 35px; /* 35px in from the right */
  color: white;
  font-size: .5rem;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4169E2;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
}

.edit-img-btn i {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<span class="image-wrapper">
  <span class="image-cropper" style=" width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="">
    
  </span>
  <button class="edit-img-btn" id="btnOpenFileDialog"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>
  <input type="file" id="fileLoader" style="display: none;" />
</span>
```

Comment: Ok, but how come wrapping it with div does otherwise?

Comment: Because a div is a block level element and will expand to fill the width. A div works if you set it to display: inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Add css properties `top: 134px;` and `left: 134px;` to class `.edit-img-btn`

```js
document.querySelector('#btnOpenFileDialog').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('#fileLoader').click();
});
```

```css
.image-cropper {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.edit-img-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 134px;
  left: 134px;
  color: white;
  font-size: .5rem;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4169E2;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.21);
}

.edit-img-btn i {
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<span class="image-cropper" style=" width: 150px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="assets/images/avatar.jpg" alt="">
  </span>

<input type="file" id="fileLoader" style="display: none;" />

<button class="edit-img-btn" id="btnOpenFileDialog"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>
```